# deleting .txt files holding identical copies of numpy arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy

I need an efficient way to eliminate duplicate integer np arrays stored in text files.  Here's the situation:

In folder C:\z_data\6_8_arrays, there are several thousand small text files, each holding one array of the same shape (in this case having 6 rows and 8 columns).   The text files have the following format:

```
0 4 5 7 3 4 6 2
8 6 0 9 9 1 2 4
6 6 7 4 5 6 3 1
3 1 3 2 3 3 5 3
4 1 2 0 9 6 0 0
9 9 8 2 4 1 0 1
```

While many of the text arrays are unique, there is also massive duplication.  Some of the arrays may even appear in identical copies 25 to 30 times.

**Question:  Is there an efficient way to delete the text files (.txt) that hold duplicate arrays?**

I'd imagine that the first step would involve loading all of the text arrays in the folder into a (6,8,n) numpy array, then eliminating the duplicates.  The biggest challenge, though, is that I need to actually then delete the duplicate text files from the folder.
If a given array appears identically in, say, 10 of the files, I need to eliminate 9 of them.  It does not matter which of the 10 files is kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and leverage the fact that testing for set membership is fast, so I  generate a hash digest for each file so that I don't need to allocate memory to hold the entire contents of all the files at once. I assume the files are generated by a program and therefore the layout and spacings in the file are consistent with each other.

- create empty set for hash digests
- iterate over all text files generating hash digest for each
- if digest is already in set, delete file, else add digest to set

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import hashlib
from pathlib import Path

# Empty set of hash digests seen so far
seen = set()

# Iterate over all text files
for filename in Path('.').glob('*.txt'):

    # Read entire file and generate hash digest of its contents
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        digest = hashlib.sha256(f.read()).digest()

    # Test if same as any other
    if digest in seen:
        print(f'Would delete {filename}')
        #Path(filename).unlink()
    else:
        seen.add(digest)
```

I generated 8,000 files similar to yours and deleted the duplicates in around a second.

Obviously please test this on a **copy** of your files.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best of approaches, but can help.

```
import os
arr_files = os.listdir('<path_with_numpy_array_files>')
array_list = np.empty((1, 6,8))
for arr_file in arr_files:
    flag = 0
    # load the numpy array
    arr = np.loadtxt(arr_file)       # shape of this will be 6x8
    arr_3 = arr.reshape((-1,6,8))
    for entry in array_list:
        # check if it already exists in our array list
        if np.array_equal(entry, arr):
            # array already there, can discard that file
            print('file to be discarded', arr_file)
            flag = 1
            # os.remove(arr_file)
    if flag == 0:
        array_list = np.concatenate((array_list, arr_3), axis=0)
```

Comment: I would define `array_list=[]`, a real list (not an array posing as one),  Append to a list is faster (than `stack`; and also faster to iterate through.

Comment: Have you actually tested this?  `np.stack` adds a new dimension each time it's called!   It's also picky about the dimensions of the arrays in its argument list.

Comment: Yes, I have tested this. stacking using `axis=0` will keep the dimensions of array_list as `6x8xn` and using for loop, we are iterating over n

Comment: `array_list` starts as (6,8).  Then becomes (2,6,8).  Then it attempts to join that with a (6,8) resulting an error.